# Fastest way to update a large table from another (large) table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two large tables (~40M rows each) in Oracle. 
I need to update tableA with data from tableB based on a single join. 
I've tried:

```
update tableA a
set (a.column2)=
(select b.column2 from tableB b
where a.column1=b.column1)
```

It works, but takes around 1 hour to complete.

I also checked the following (explain plan):

```
merge into tableA a
using (select b.column1, b.column2 from tableB b) b
on (a.column1=b.column1)
when matched then
update set a.column2=b.column2
```

But its cost seems to be 10 times the cost of the first query.
I also tried to update using a cursor but it took 2 hours to complete.

Both tables have index on column1.
TableA also has partitions on a monthly basis.

Any ideas how to do this process in a more efficient way ?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you ran the merge statement?

Answer (score 2):

I would try adding a `where` clause to the first query:

```
update tableA a
    set a.column2 = (select b.column2 from tableB b
where a.column1 = b.column1)
    where a.column2 <> (select b.column2 from tableB b
where a.column1 = b.column1);
```

(This assumes the destination value is not `NULL`.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the below way ?

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT tableA.column2 as OLD, tableB.column2 as NEW
 FROM tableA
 INNER JOIN tableB
 ON tableA.column1 = tableB.column1
) t
SET t.old = t.new
```

Comment: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Comment: I know it doesn't work for the OP, but your way is very good in cases where the view (the `SELECT` statement you are updating) is key-preserved.

Answer (score 1):

for bulk inserts or updates i would go for forall in oracle. 
The below code might have some errors but you can correct it and use for bulk processing

```
declare
c_limit number:10000;
CURSOR c_update IS
SELECT b.column1,b.column2 from tableB b,tableA a  where a.column1=b.column1
type upd_Arry is table of c_update%rowtype;
upd_val  upd_Arry;

BEGIN
    OPEN c_update;
    LOOP
    FETCH c_update BULK COLLECT INTO upd_val LIMIT c_limit;

    FORALL i IN 1..l_data.COUNT
    update tableA 
      set column2=upd_val(i).b.column2
      where column1=upd_val(i).b.column1;

    EXIT WHEN c_update%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    commit;
    CLOSE c_update;
END ;
```